# Считывание большого файла

Tags: c#, файлы, ввод

Появилась проблема со считыванием большого файла. Индекс массива, в который записываются строки(array[i]), останавливается на 174 и всё. Можно ли как-то увеличить размер массива array или прибегнуть к каким-то другим способам считать весь файл?

```
using System.IO;

namespace Agl1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            var array = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt");
            var len = int.Parse(array[0]);
            var numbers = new int[len];
            var value = new string[len];
            var max = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < len + 1; i++)
            {
                var per = int.Parse(array[i]);
                numbers[i - 1] = per;
                if (per > max)
                {
                    max = per;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

И вот сам файл input.txt: http://wdfiles.ru/65i4

Comment: Считывание большого файла обычно не делается через ReadAllLines... а через StreamReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так в приложенном файле именно 174 строки. Метод `ReadAllLines` считывает все строки файла в массив строк `array`. Таким образом размер `array` как раз 174.

Вероятно, ошибка здесь `var len = int.Parse(array[0]);`. Переменная длины определяется не по размеру массива, а по значению первой строки. Размер массива можно получить через свойство `var len = array.Length`.